# How can I override Radix UI Tooltip.Root component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using the Radix UI [tooltip](https://www.radix-ui.com/docs/primitives/components/tooltip), and I am trying to override the styling of the Tooltip.Root component.

I am able to override the other Tooltip components as seen below, but this doesn't work for Tooltip.Root:

```
import * as TooltipPrimitive from "@radix-ui/react-tooltip";
const StyledTooltipTrigger = styled(TooltipPrimitive.Trigger, {
  display: "flex",
  border: "none",
  background: "transparent",
  padding: 0,
  textAlign: "start",
});
```

In short, I have a div that is inside the Tooltip.Trigger that I need to expand to `width: 100%`, however, the Tooltip prevents this div from expanding.